# Vertically center `matrix of math nodes` on baseline

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, matrices, tikz-matrix

I want to typeset matrices with `matrix of math nodes`. However, I am having trouble with vertical centering. In the following, I expect the equal sign to be in the middle of the two matrix rows.

[image]

How can I achieve this consistently?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{%
  tikz matrix/.style={
      matrix of math nodes,
      minimum size=12pt,
      row sep=1pt,
      column sep=1pt,
      left delimiter={\lbrack},
      right delimiter={\rbrack},
      inner xsep=0pt,
      nodes in empty cells,
      nodes={font=\footnotesize},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  M =
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \matrix (m)[tikz matrix]{
      1 & 2  & 9  & 3 \\
      1 & -3 & -6 & 3 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One not satisfying way to achieve that is to add `yshift=3pt` to your matrix definition.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps with a different tool and much less typing.

`nicematrix` uses `tikz` internally.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{nicematrix}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    $M= \begin{bNiceMatrix}
            1 & 2  & 9  & 3 \\
            1 & -3 & -6 & 3 \\
        \end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the `baseline`, you can place the `tikzpicture` with the matrix inside `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`. For comparison here is your matrix next to a standard `matrix` with `Bigg` delimiters.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{%
  tikz matrix/.style={
      matrix of math nodes,
      minimum size=12pt,
      row sep=1pt,
      column sep=1pt,
      left delimiter={\lbrack},
      right delimiter={\rbrack},
      inner xsep=0pt,
      nodes in empty cells,
      nodes={font=\footnotesize},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  M =\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m)[tikz matrix]{
      1 & 2  & 9  & 3 \\
      1 & -3 & -6 & 3 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}}}\Biggl[\begin{matrix}1&2&9&3\\1&-3&-6&3\end{matrix}\Biggr]
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `calc` library to choose your vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{%
  tikz matrix/.style={
      matrix of math nodes,
      minimum size=12pt,
      row sep=1pt,
      column sep=1pt,
      left delimiter={\lbrack},
      right delimiter={\rbrack},
      inner xsep=0pt,
      nodes in empty cells,
      nodes={font=\footnotesize},
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  M =
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={($(m-1-1)!.5!(m-2-1)$)}]
    \matrix (m)[tikz matrix]{
      1 & 2  & 9  & 3 \\
      1 & -3 & -6 & 3 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  M =
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]$(m-1-1)!.5!(m-2-1)$)}]
    \matrix (m)[tikz matrix]{
      1 & 2  & 9  & 3 \\
      1 & -3 & -6 & 3 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The first example is your requirement. The second example is my proposition.

[image]

Comment: I think `baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]m.center)}` or even `baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)}` should be good to go.

Comment: It's close, but not exact. Add `=\Biggl[X\Biggr]` after the tikzpicture to see that the brackets don't quite line up.